# VBA dynamic range

Tags: excel, vba

Fairly new to VBA. I have a macro that I'd like to change to be able to work on however many rows containing data are in the worksheet rather than the hardcoded value (46).

```
Sub test1calc()
'
' test1calc Macro
'

'
'1 - UNSTRESSED POSTED PRODUCT LEVEL BREAKDOWN SUMMED AT NETTING SET
    Columns("AS:AS").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Range("AS1").Select
    Selection.Interior.Pattern = xlSolid
    Selection.Interior.PatternColorIndex = 2
    Selection.Interior.Color = 65535
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Unstressed Posted Total"
    Range("AS2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(RC[-30]:RC[-1])"
    Range("AS2").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("AS2:AS46")
    Range("AS2:AS46").Select
    ActiveSheet.Calculate
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

Comment: when you say `"however many rows are in the worksheet"` do you mean the number of rows relative to some existing data? Surely you don't want to fill millions of rows?

Comment: Correct. So ideally the macro would work on 46 rows, 1000 rows, 100000 rows, etc.. Just on however many rows have data.  Not blank rows

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you want to fill the rows where there is existing data to the left, not the millions of rows that exist in your worksheet.

If so, I believe your code can be simplified to the following:

```
Sub test1calc()

    '1 - UNSTRESSED POSTED PRODUCT LEVEL BREAKDOWN SUMMED AT NETTING SET

    Columns("AS:AS").Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove

    With Range("AS1")
        .Interior.Pattern = xlSolid
        .Interior.PatternColorIndex = 2
        .Interior.Color = 65535
        .Value = "Unstressed Posted Total"
    End With

    With Range("AS2:AS" & Range("O" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
         .FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(RC[-30]:RC[-1])"
         .Value = .Value
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: no worries, don't forget to mark as the answer/upvote if it solved your issue :)